# Is there an analytic expression for this recursive sum? $C_n = \sum _{k=0}^{n-1}C_k C_{n-1-k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Is there an analytic expression for this recursive sum ? Say ,
$C_n = ?$

\begin{align*}
C_n =& \sum _{k=0}^{n-1}C_k C_{n-1-k}  \\
    =& C_0C_{n-1} + C_1C_{n-2}+\cdots+C_{n-1}C_0
\end{align*}

Comment: Are these supposed to be binomial coefficients (i.e. combinations), or just some generic numbers?

Comment: @AlexM.  With one index, they can hardly be binomial coefficients. Just a recurrence relation.

Comment: @2mkgz: Exactly, I just want to be sure. This means that Mann's answer below is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** One may recall the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product):
$$ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \right)\!\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n A_k B_{n-k}\right), \tag1
$$
then use it with $A_n=B_n=C_nx^n$ to get 
$$ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n\right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n C_k C_{n-k}\right)\!x^n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k C_{n-1-k}\right)\!x^{n-1}. \tag2
$$
**By hypothesis**, the latter series is equal to $\displaystyle  \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n x^{n-1}$,  thus $(2)$ rewrites
$$ \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n\right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n x^{n-1} \tag3
$$$$ x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n\right)-C_0 \tag4
$$
Setting $\displaystyle f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n $,  the ordinary generating function of the numbers $C_n$, then $(4)$ reads
$$
x\:(f(x))^2=f(x)-C_0 \tag5
$$ giving 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 C_0 x}}{2 x} \tag6
$$ for appropriate $C_0$.
Using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), $(6)$ leads to
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\times (C_0)^{n+1}\times x^n \tag7
$$ and we conclude by identification between $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n$ and $(7)$ to get

> $$
> C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\times (C_0)^{n+1}. \tag8
> $$

The case $C_0=1$ gives [Catalan's numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is known as the [Catalan sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):
with $C_0 =1$:

$$
C_n = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}
$$

Comment: yes, possible. I made a simplification anyway.